# No adapter attached; skipping layout kotlin

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

It loads fine at startup but when I navigate to other fragments and go back to Home Fragment, the recycler view doesn't load anymore. It loads fine with other fragments when I navigate back to it, only the recycler view of Home Fragment doesn't show. There is no error showing in the logcat. Only this W/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout. Anyone can help me? I don't know what's really wrong here. Thank you in advance guys.

Here is my code of HOME FRAGMENT

```
class HomeFragment : Fragment() {

private lateinit var homeViewModel: HomeViewModel

var recyclerView:RecyclerView?=null
lateinit var swipeUpToRefresh:SwipeRefreshLayout
private var viewPager:LoopingViewPager?=null

private var layoutAnimationController:LayoutAnimationController?=null

private var _binding: FragmentHomeBinding? = null
private val binding get() = _binding!!

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View {
    homeViewModel =
        ViewModelProvider(this).get(HomeViewModel::class.java)
    _binding = FragmentHomeBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
    val root: View = binding.root

    val key = requireArguments().getString("restaurant")

    initView(root)
    refreshPage()
    //bind data
        homeViewModel.getPopularList(key!!).observe(viewLifecycleOwner, {
            val listData = it
            val adapter = MyPopularCategoriesAdapter(requireContext(), listData)
            recyclerView!!.adapter = adapter
            recyclerView!!.layoutAnimation = layoutAnimationController
        })
        homeViewModel.getBestDealList(key).observe(viewLifecycleOwner, {
            val adapter = MyBestDealsAdapter(requireContext(), it, false)
            viewPager!!.adapter = adapter
        })
    return root
}

private fun refreshPage() {
    val key = requireArguments().getString("restaurant")
    swipeUpToRefresh.setOnRefreshListener {
        //bind data
        homeViewModel.getPopularList(key!!).observe(viewLifecycleOwner, {
            val listData = it
            val adapter = MyPopularCategoriesAdapter(requireContext(), listData)
            recyclerView!!.adapter = adapter
            recyclerView!!.layoutAnimation = layoutAnimationController
        })
        homeViewModel.getBestDealList(key).observe(viewLifecycleOwner, {
            val adapter = MyBestDealsAdapter(requireContext(), it, false)
            viewPager!!.adapter = adapter
        })
        swipeUpToRefresh.isRefreshing = false
    }
}

private fun initView(root:View) {
    swipeUpToRefresh = root.findViewById(R.id.refresh) as SwipeRefreshLayout

    layoutAnimationController = AnimationUtils.loadLayoutAnimation(context, R.anim.layout_item_from_left)

    viewPager = root.findViewById(R.id.viewpager) as LoopingViewPager

    recyclerView = root.findViewById(R.id.recycler_popular) as RecyclerView
    recyclerView!!.setHasFixedSize(true)
    recyclerView!!.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context, RecyclerView.HORIZONTAL, false)
}

override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    viewPager!!.resumeAutoScroll()
}

override fun onPause() {
    viewPager!!.pauseAutoScroll()
    super.onPause()
}

override fun onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView()
    _binding = null
}}
```

Comment: It skips loading the recylerView layout because you are assigning an adapter only when you observe new data. This is wrong. Assign the adapter no matter what. When observer sends you new data, design a logic that updates the adapter and the recyclerView data.

Comment: can you provide a sample code? i don't have any idea how to do it. sorry for the trouble.

Comment: If you have solved your problem, consider adding your own answer, instead of editing the title.

Comment: okay, sorry. my bad :(

Answer (score 0):

I added this line of code to my HomeActivity in R.id.nav_home

```
val bundle = Bundle()
bundle.putString("restaurant",Common.currentRestaurant!!.uid)
                    navController.navigate(R.id.nav_home,bundle)
```

here Is my navView

```
navView!!.setNavigationItemSelectedListener { p0 ->
            p0.isChecked = true
            drawer!!.closeDrawers()

            if (p0.itemId == R.id.nav_sign_out) {
                signOut()
            } else if (p0.itemId == R.id.nav_restaurant) {
                if (menuItemClick != p0.itemId)
                    navController.popBackStack()
                navController.navigate(R.id.nav_restaurant)
            } else if (p0.itemId == R.id.nav_home) {
                if (menuItemClick != p0.itemId) {
                    EventBus.getDefault().postSticky(MenuInflateEvent(true))
                    navController.popBackStack()
                    val bundle = Bundle()
                    bundle.putString("restaurant",Common.currentRestaurant!!.uid)
                    navController.navigate(R.id.nav_home,bundle)
                }
            } else if (p0.itemId == R.id.nav_cart) {
                if (menuItemClick != p0.itemId) {
                    EventBus.getDefault().postSticky(MenuInflateEvent(true))
                    navController.popBackStack()
                    navController.navigate(R.id.nav_cart)
                }
            } else if (p0.itemId == R.id.nav_menu) {
                if (menuItemClick != p0.itemId) {
                    EventBus.getDefault().postSticky(MenuInflateEvent(true))
                    navController.popBackStack()
                    navController.navigate(R.id.nav_menu)
                }
            } else if (p0.itemId == R.id.nav_view_order) {
                if (menuItemClick != p0.itemId) {
                    EventBus.getDefault().postSticky(MenuInflateEvent(true))
                    navController.popBackStack()
                    navController.navigate(R.id.nav_view_order)
                }
            } else if (p0.itemId == R.id.nav_update_info) {
                showUpdateDialog()
            }

            menuItemClick = p0.itemId

            true
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try doing this

```kotlin
private fun initView(root:View) {
    swipeUpToRefresh = root.findViewById(R.id.refresh) as SwipeRefreshLayout

    layoutAnimationController = AnimationUtils.loadLayoutAnimation(context, R.anim.layout_item_from_left)

    viewPager = root.findViewById(R.id.viewpager) as LoopingViewPager
   
    recyclerView = root.findViewById(R.id.recycler_popular) as RecyclerView
    //Here is where you need to initialize an adapter to the recyclerView
    recylerView!!.adapter = MyPopularCategoriesAdapter(requireContext(), listData) //I'm not sure what is the second argument of your adapter. Feel free to change it as you like.
    recyclerView!!.setHasFixedSize(true)
    recyclerView!!.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context, RecyclerView.HORIZONTAL, false)
}
```

Comment: thank you for taking your time answering my question. but I already solved it :) thank you very much!